# Get local specific Date using DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, date-format

I have been trying to convert some date into locale specific format.
For say I have the date : 17 January 2019

I want to translate this date for below locales:

```
localized time for en-GB: 17 January 2019
localized time for es-ES: 17 de enero de 2019 
localized time for zh-CN: 2019年1月17日 
localized time for de-DE: 17. Januar 2019 
localized time for fr-FR: 17 janvier 2019 
localized time for it-IT: 17 gennaio 2019 
localized time for ja-JP: 2019年1月17日 
localized time for ko-KR: 2019년 1월 17일
```

I tried multiple ways to achieve this:

Approach 1:

```
final DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM,
                Locale.forLanguageTag(locale)));
```

Output for different locales:

```
localized time for en-GB: 17 January 2019
localized time for es-ES: 17 de enero de 2019 
localized time for zh-CN: 2019年1月17日 
localized time for de-DE: 17. Januar 2019 
localized time for fr-FR: 17 janvier 2019 
localized time for it-IT: 17 gennaio 2019 
localized time for ja-JP: 2019/01/17 [Getting the date in numerical form]
localized time for ko-KR: 2019년 1월 17일 (목) [Getting this extra character at the end for ko-KR]
```

Approach 2:

```
        ZonedDateTime zoned = ZonedDateTime.now();
    DateTimeFormatter pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL).withLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag(locale));
```

Output for different locales:

```
zoned fek long ja-JP:  2019年1月17日                                                                                                    
zoned fek long ko-KR:  2019년 1월 17일 목요일                                                                                           
zoned fek long es-ES:  jueves 17 de enero de 2019                                                                                       
zoned fek long fr-FR:  jeudi 17 janvier 2019                                                                                            
zoned fek long it-IT:  giovedì 17 gennaio 2019                                                                                          
zoned fek long de-DE:  Donnerstag, 17. Januar 2019                                                                                      
zoned fek long ko-KR:  jeudi 17 janvier 2019
```

In this approach JP looks fine but all other locales had also Day in the output.

I have to show the dates as it is mentioned in the above.

Comment: Did you try `FormatStyle.LONG`? It should be something between `MEDIUM` and `FULL`. If the results are not satisfactory, you will probably need to choose different format styles for different locales.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `DateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Your approach 2 is much better.

Comment: Tried using FormatStyle.LONG with DateTimeFormatter, getting the same result what I was getting with approach one.

Comment: How do I select different format style for different locale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edit: CLDR

Run your approach 2 with the command line option `-Djava.locale.providers=CLDR,COMPAT`. For example:

```
java -Djava.locale.providers=CLDR,COMPAT YourApp
```

Output:

> ```
> zoned fek long en-GB: 17 January 2019
> zoned fek long es-ES: 17 de enero de 2019
> zoned fek long zh-CN: 2019年1月17日
> zoned fek long de-DE: 17. Januar 2019
> zoned fek long fr-FR: 17 janvier 2019
> zoned fek long it-IT: 17 gennaio 2019
> zoned fek long ja-JP: 2019年1月17日
> zoned fek long ko-KR: 2019년 1월 17일
> ```

I discovered that on my Java 9 I could not reproduce your problem. With `FormatStyle.LONG` I got `2019年1月17日` for Japanese where you reported `2019/01/17`. Java gets the date formats as part of its locale data from different sources. From Java 8 locale data from [Unicode Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository) come with Java, but Java’s own locale data are used as default. From Java 9 it’s the other way around, CLDR data are used as default. So what I do with the above command line option is I tell your Java 8 to use CLDR before Java’s own. Java’s own locale data are specified as COMPAT.

The other option of course is to upgrade to Java 9, 10 or 11. This too will give you the result you asked for.

### Java 8 without command line option

> Can not add any additional option in the command line since this
>   application will run th[r]ough a different system.

That’s unfortunate. You may want to ask once more. On the other hand, the command line option risks changing behaviour in all parts of that other system, so you may not get through that way.

If all else fails, code some exceptions for the locales where the `FormatStyle.LONG` doesn’t give you what is required. [The answer by Joop Eggen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54238723/5772882) shows one way of doing this.

Once the managers of that other system decide to upgrade to Java 9 or later, unless they use a command line option to use `COMAPT` before `CLDR`, locale data will change and you will then have the opportunity to simplify your code.

Comment: Can not add any additional option in the command line since this application will run though a different system.

Answer (score 3):

As you do not want to list all locales with a custom format, patching the exceptions seems better. That could be a custom pattern, or simply picking another style / post-editing.

```
String[] locales = {"en-GB", "es-ES", "zh-CN", "de-DE", "fr-FR", "it-IT",
    "ja-JP", "ko-KR", "ko-KP"};
for (String loc : locales) {
    String[] langCtry = loc.split("-");
    Locale locale = new Locale(langCtry[0], langCtry[1]);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    LocalDate.set(2019, 1, 17);
    FormatStyle style = locale.getLanguage().equals("ja") ? FormatStyle.FULL 
                                                          : FormatStyle.LONG;
    DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(style);
    String text = format.format(date);
    if (locale.getLanguage().equals("ko")) {
        text = text.replaceFirst("\\s\\S+$", "");
    }
    System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", locale, text);
}
```

This **patches** both **ja** and **ko**, in different ways.

A unit test suite to check for the expected might be useful, as locale specific data may change over time.